# Ruby unknown action error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In AdminController I am having two methods 1. update 2. update_admin

in admin/admin_edit.erb

```
>% form_for(@admin, :url => update_admin_admin_path, :method => post, :html => {:id => 'user_edit_form'}) do |f| %>
```

In routes.rb

```
  resources :admin
    member do
      post :updaate_admin
   end
  end
```

On form post I am expecting the url '/admin/update_admin/2' but the url '/admin/2/update_admin' is triggered. Because of this I am getting the error

```
The action '2' could not be found for AdminController
```

On form post action I want to call update_admin method. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of post :update_admin I modified put :update_admin. Now it works fine for me.